# How to embed icons inside an HTML table obtained from a csv?

Tags: php, html

The php code below extracts the data from a .csv file and generates an HTML table. It works fine. I wonder if it is possible to embed in the html table some icons, such as a red or green dot (reddot.gif , greendot.gif) in correspondence of some specific words (example: red , green) in the csv file.

In other words, when in the csv file appear red or green in a specific column (example: column 3), should appear the reddot.gif or greendot.gif in the generated html file.

Thanks in advance. Mat

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {

        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
// ------------- head row --------
            echo '<td style="border-top: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224); border-left: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224); border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224);"  align="left" bgcolor="#0066cc" height="36" valign="middle" ><b><font color="#ffffff" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></b></td>';
        }else{

// ------------- Generic row -------
            echo '<td style=" border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(111,180,224);" sdval="9" sdnum="1040;" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="25"  valign="middle"><font color="#000000" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$value.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
echo '</center>';   
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare this function **outside** of any loops, just at the beginning of the if, or even at the beginning or ending of the script:

```
function img($img){ return "<img src='{$img}dot.gif'/>";}
```

this goes in the else:

```
$value = preg_replace(array('/red/i', '/green/i'), array(img('red'), img('green')), $data[$c]);
```

---

If you need more colors just follow the logic and add them in the two arrays inside of the preg_replace.

If you need to add attributes to the images add them in the function declared.

Hope it works for you

Comment: Ok, it works! But if the word "green" or "red" is part of a generic text it displays the img inside the word :/

Comment: then you should apply the code only to the column you desire. lets say it's the column 3, inside the for loop: if($c == 2){ value replacing for images code }

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try.

```
    if(empty($data[$c])) {
       $value = "&nbsp;";
    }else{
       $value = $data[$c];
       switch(strtolower(trim($value))){
       case 'green': $value = '<img src="greendot.gif" '
                             .'alt="green" height="32" width="32">';
                             break;
       case 'red':   $value = '<img src="reddot.gif" '
                             .'alt="red" height="32" width="32">';
                             break;
       // you can add other cases here like blue, triangle etc :)
       }
    }
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify if those fields would only contain the word with the colour, you should, at least trim the $value, as the comma separated values usually comes with a whitespace. And if it's a word mixed with other words you should use REGEX instead.

Comment: @aleation How about overcomplicating things? Lets add a parser then ;)... Anyway thanks for the trim tip, leading and trailing spaces in csv is common.. The answer I present here is neither exact nor precise, since I can not know the OP side with data presented here. i.e: The paths to the images are ommitted and sizes are arbitrary. The motive here is to show the pattern... Thanks for your interest.

Comment: It doesn't work indeed. The idea to not specify a column is not bad, so i can use freely more than one column with icons without modify the code, but apart this i tried the code and didn't give me the hoped result :/

Comment: Keep adjusting until you get your desired result. What went wrong anyway?

Comment: as you can see in my answer using a regex is not actually "overcomplicating". it's much shorter code, and worked out at first. I guess on your code the problem was the handling of the upper/lower cases. A switch case is unefficient to compare strings, I would use it only to check variable values on the code where you can know the exact values, not data from third parties. At least you should use a stripos I think.

Comment: Oh, I liked your answer. +1 for your efforts... Edited mine for a lowercase. A switch case is more than enough for a person who knows what kind of data he is dealing with... As I told before. Did OP understand what you have done? Possibly no. What I have done? I do not have a hope too... Well I wish the best for you... And It was nice to meet you... come to php chat sometimes...